# cross validation on my own classification algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

How can I use the crossval function of matlab for my own implemented linear regression classification? I do not want to use the matlab classifiers such as "regress" or "classify". I have a function called "myClassify" which its inputs and output are exactly the same as matlab "classify" function.

And here is the way I call the classifier:

```
classifier = @(XTRAIN, ytrain,XTEST)(myClassify(XTEST,XTRAIN,ytrain));
MCR = crossval('mcr',X,y,'predfun',classifier,'partition',cp);
```

In which myClassify is a function which outputs the predicted binary values (either 1 or 0).
And the error is:

> Undefined function or method 'minus' for input arguments of type
>   'nominal'.

Thanks

Comment: That should work exactly like when using MATLAB's functions. Have you read through the [`crossval` help page](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html)?

Comment: Yes, I have read it. But I get an strange error about "minus" in my own classification function when use it in crossval. I edited the post to show my function.